# Is there a way to run store_result and get_result together

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to use `store_result()`  and `get_result()` in the same query but it says

`Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean`

Some tutorial on the Internet claims to use both of them and I guess it is working for him.

this is my code

```
$stmtgetproducts = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM store_products sp 
              INNER JOIN store_product_categories spc ON sp.product_category=spc.id 
              WHERE sp.store_id = ? ORDER BY sp.product_views DESC");
            $stmtgetproducts->bind_param("i",$storeid);
            $stmtgetproducts->execute();

            $stmtgetproducts->store_result();
            $rows = $stmtgetproducts->num_rows;

            $getproducts = $stmtgetproducts->get_result();

while($products = $getproducts->fetch_assoc()){
     //Code to display rows.
}
```

Comment: Your query is probably failing, did you try it directly in the database?

Comment: Query is working. if I remove `$stmtgetproducts->store_result();`
            `$rows = $stmtgetproducts->num_rows;` query works. Products display.

Comment: Remove this statment `$stmtgetproducts->store_result();`. Simply do `$getproducts = $stmtgetproducts->get_result();` followed by `$rows = $getproducts->num_rows;`

Comment: Yess that works @RajdeepPaul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete this question, you can use num_rows with get_result as well

```
$getproducts = $stmtgetproducts->get_result();
$rows = $getproducts->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way. You must use only one of them. Just use `get_result` all the time.

Note that `num_rows` is [rather useless anyway](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#num_rows).